# Strange hang while attempting mounting LVM2 in recovery mode

Tags: rhel, data-recovery, lvm

I am running a RHEL 7 vm and I am trying to mount an LVM disk in recovery mode.

I can see the disk with fdisk -l.

lvscan shows it being active.

When I try to mount the disk to the system

I see the following:

```
#mount /dev/vg_data/lv_data /mnt
mount:
```

It just sits here and appears to hang. Can someone give me an insight into why this might be happening?